# Reading database from file c++

Tags: c++, database, class, io

I'm trying to read my database from file.

Here is my save_base method:

```
void data_base::save_base()
{
    fstream file;

    file.open("base.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);

    if(file.good()==true) {
        node *p = new node();
        p=first;

        while(p) {
            file << p->content->connect() << ";" << "\n";
            p=p->next;
        }
        file.close();
    }else{
    cout << "Err - opening file." << endl;
    }
}
```

connect method:

```
string product::connect() {

    ostringstream do_string;
    do_string << lp;
    string new_lp = do_string.str();

    ostringstream do_string1;
    do_string1 << count;
    string new_count = do_string1.str();

    ostringstream do_string2;
    do_string2 << prize;
    string new_prize = do_string2.str();

    ostringstream do_string3;
    do_string3 << vat;
    string new_vat = do_string3.str();

    string connected = type + ";" + new_lp + ";" + name + ";" + new_count + ";" + unit + ";" + new_prize + ";" + new_vat;
    return connected;
}
```

and read_base method:

```
void data_base::read_base()
{
    fstream file;

    file.open("base.dat", ios::in);
    if(file.good()==true)
    {
        char data_row[50];
        int i=1;
        while(!file.eof()) {
            file.getline(data_row,100);

        string data_content[50];
        int j = 0;

        char *buff;
        buff = strtok (data_row,";");
        while (buff != NULL)    {
            data_content[j] = buff;
            buff = strtok (NULL, ";");
            j++;
        }
        string type = data_content[0];
        int lp;
        istringstream iss1(data_content[1]);
        iss1 >> lp;
        double count;
        istringstream iss2(data_content[3]);
        iss2 >> count;
        double prize;
        istringstream iss3(data_content[5]);
        iss3 >> prize;
        double vat;
        istringstream iss4(data_content[5]);
        iss4 >> vat;

        // Sprawdzamy typ obiektu zapisanego w danym wierszu pliku
        if(type == "product")
        {

            product new_prod(lp, data_content[2], count, data_content[4], prize, vat);
            product *new_product = new product(new_prod);
            this->add(new_product);
        }
        i++;
        }
    file.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Err opening file." << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm adding some products to database and it works fine. Even saving to file works great. But the main problem is when i'm trying to read database from file. Reading database from file works fine, but at the end, application won't end by itself. I think that there are still some buffers to close. But i don't know which or how close them.

Comment: So when you look in your debugger, where is the application stopped if it doesn't end?

Comment: Sounds like your application is stuck in an endless loop. Start it up in the debugger and when you're satisfied it is in a stuck state "break" the applications execution (Debug Menu->Break All or something similar).

Comment: call stacks:

#0 7755000D ntdll!LdrFindResource_U() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#1 775DF896 ntdll!RtlQueryTimeZoneInformation() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#2 74B4F499 ?? () (??:??)
#3 ?? ?? () (??:??)

Comment: `node *p = new node(); p=first;` You just leaked memory in two short lines. This isn't Java. And not having something we can actually test will make this a *long* road.

Comment: so there is pastebin of my app

http://pastebin.com/psD1ZAid

Comment: Before I post my answer, is there a specific reason `class data_base` inherits from `product` (which happens to also be the record content held *inside* the database as well) ?

Comment: honestly, no. there is no specific reason.

Comment: Since when is `data_base` a kind-of `product`? That's some funky class design you've got going down there.

Comment: I have more classes that inherits from product. That's why i accidentally wrote that.

Comment: I compiled the code from the pastebin, and I was not able to reproduce any issues. What are the exact steps that you're taking?

Comment: At first i'm adding new product. Then i'm calling method show from class data_base. Then i'm saving database to file. Closing program. Running it again. Checking db with show method from class data_base. Reading from file. Showing db again and trying to close app by choosing 6 to close app. And it just stuck.

Comment: You've got your allocations wrong. The application fails while executing the destructor of `data_base`. Valgrind tells me that this is due to a double `free`, which - in this case - means that `delete` was called twice on a pointer that has already been `delete`d. Try assigning `NULL` values to pointers after you `delete` them.

Comment: assingning NULL to first and p after deleting first in ~data_base?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly - you have quite a lot of problems going on in this code, and I'd suggest that your main problem is that you're perhaps still wrestling with encapsulation. Your code uses a mix of C and C++ styles which are guaranteed to make code hard to read and thus maintain, and that's why you're here and people are struggling to give you the answer.

That said, the problem looks to be that in save you're calling "new node()" which looks like you'd be saving ... nothing. Shouldn't you be querying some existing value within the product? edit: Ah - no, you re-assign it to be "p = first" now, I see. So what happens to the node you allocated on the previous line?

You also have a potential stack-clobber when any of your lines exceed 50 bytes:

```
char data_row[50];
int i=1;
while(!file.eof()) {
    file.getline(data_row,100);
```

If you have to use char arrays, get yourself into the habbit of using sizeof:

```
file.getline(data_row, sizeof(data_row));
```

It took me a few moments to figure out what the istringstreams were for - you're trying to convert strings to numbers? Could be simpler and more efficient written as:

```
unsigned int lp = atoi(data_content[1].c_str());
or
unsigned int lp = strtoul(data_content[1].c_str(), NULL, 10);
```

Your read_base function, which is part of the database, knows WAAAAY too much about data records. You need to encapsulate the record population away so that read_base looks more like:

```
void data_base::read_base()
{
    fstream file("base.dat", ios::in);
    if(file.good() == false) {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
        return;
    }

    for(size_t rowNo = 0; !file.eof(); ++rowNo) {
        row* row = data_type::make_object_from_row(file);
        if(row != nullptr)
            this->add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to look into the "Factory pattern" for how to implement a data_row base type that will let you do this. But in short, you make product inherit data_type so that the above works. data_type::make_object_from_row would read the first part of the row and enumerate the type so it can do something like:

```
data_type* data_type::make_object_row_row(istream& file) {
    switch(get_type(file)) {
        case DATA_TYPE_PRODUCT: return new product(file);
        case DATA_TYPE_PERSON: return new person(file);
        default:
          clog << "invalid type in database: " << type << endl;
          return nullptr;
    }
}
```

(this is just one possible approach).

Comment: Let me add: If you're going to do it textually like this, you might want to look further into [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) 

But you may also want to look into the ways you can use imbue() to tell a stream about separators so  it knows to look for ; rather than white space, so you can do something like:
`product::read(istream& file) { ... file >> lp >> name >> ...; }` and `product::write(ostream& file) { ... file << lp << separator << name << separator << ...; }`

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one obvious error that may produce undefined behavior. You are allocating 50 bytes but read up to 100.

```
    char data_row[50];
    int i=1;
    while(!file.eof()) {
        file.getline(data_row,100);
```

I would suggest change 50 to 100 in this code.

Comment: And when they need to access more than 100 bytes they get UB again. Change it to `std::string` and use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious agree with you but as far as I remember there is no `getline` overload that accepts `std::string`. So using `std::string` will involve more than just two characters change =)

Comment: See [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: changing value 50 to 100 did not help.